# Powerlaw Distribution and old nodes

Tags: probability, distributions, power-law

I am working on the size of discussions (number of replies, replies to the replies) on Twitter data, and I am observing Power-law distribution for small and medium-size discussion but it is not valid for large nodes. Here is the log-log plot.

[image]

I know that for any preferential attachment process in real life there is a threshold for growth of the star. In other words, extremely large nodes that are becoming outdated are not getting much preference and that's why we may observe such a sharp decrease in the probability of exceedingly large nodes. Is there any model that considers the effect of the mentioned incident in the preferential attachment?

Comment: You refer to "Twitter data", but your plot has "energy of stars" on it, and furthermore, the powerlaw distribution fit doesn't look particularly good, contra to the statement made in your question.

Comment: The point is that two power-law distribution in different domains is observable. I searched a bit, and it seems this is a power-law with an exponential cutoff. That's why a line is not a fit to the CCDF of distribution. As for the star, this is a term, I used for the discussions. I will edit the graph.

Comment: Here starting from slide 72 there are some explanation about the case. 
http://snap.stanford.edu/class/cs224w-2015/slides/04-powerlaws.pdf